# C#：The name 'Launch' does not exist in this current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code for QR code tracking. Using a gitHub example and added a new function named 'Launch' as

```
public void Launch(string uri)
```

When I call it later, it gives:

```
The name 'Launch' does not exist in this current context
```

Is my declaration wrong or should I include in the 'QRTracking' function? Using, Unity 2019.4.14f1, Visual Studio 2019, UWP platform.  Have deleted some parts of the code with '...' to reduce the size that I thought was not relevant. Any tips would be very helpful. I am quite new in C#.

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if WINDOWS_UWP

using Windows.Perception.Spatial;

public void Launch (string uri)
 {
     Debug.Log($"LaunchUri: Launching {uri}"); 　#if WINDOWS_UWP

     UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async () =>
      {
          bool result = await global::Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new      
          System.Uri(uri));
          if (!result)
             {
                Debug.LogError("Launching URI failed to launch.");
             }
      }, false);　#else
         Application.OpenURL(uri);
         #endif
}

 #endif
  namespace QRTracking
  {
    [RequireComponent(typeof(QRTracking.SpatialGraphCoordinateSystem))]
     public class QRCode : MonoBehaviour
  　　{
      public Microsoft.MixedReality.QR.QRCode qrCode;
      private GameObject qrCodeCube;
      ....
      ....
      private bool launch = false;
      private System.Uri uriResult;
      private long lastTimeStamp = 0;

     // Use this for initialization
      void Start()
      {
         PhysicalSize = 0.1f;
         CodeText = "Dummy";
         if (qrCode == null)
         {
            throw new System.Exception("QR Code Empty");
         }

         PhysicalSize = qrCode.PhysicalSideLength;
         CodeText = qrCode.Data;

         ....
         ....
        
         QRID.text = "Id:" + qrCode.Id.ToString();
         QRNodeID.text = "NodeId:" + qrCode.SpatialGraphNodeId.ToString();
         QRText.text = CodeText;

         if (System.Uri.TryCreate(CodeText, System.UriKind.Absolute,out uriResult))
         {
            validURI = true;
            QRText.color = Color.blue;
         }
         ...
         ...
         Debug.Log("Id= " + qrCode.Id + "NodeId= " + qrCode.SpatialGraphNodeId + " PhysicalSize 
         = " + PhysicalSize + " TimeStamp = " + qrCode.SystemRelativeLastDetectedTime.Ticks + "   
         QRVersion = " + qrCode.Version + " QRData = " + CodeText);
        
         // added here

         Debug.Log("Call Launch");
         Launch("http://" + CodeText");  // -> error: Name 'Launch' does not exist in the 
         current context
    }

    .....
    .....
```

Comment: it's not in the class scope. Move it in to the class.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you have to add methods to classes, they can't just be standalone inside a namespace.

Move your `public void Launch (string uri)` method definition into a class, then it should compile at least.

Comment: Thanks! After moving the 'public void Launch' to 'QRTracking' the error is gone.

Comment: @Fakir doubt that .. it is probably in class `QRCode` now not only in the namespace `QRTracking`